# WP7 Popup in visual tree doesn't respect orientation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, popup, orientation

I know there are issues with popups and orientation. I've read that if a popup is in the visual tree, it should respect the orientation. I have two types of popups, one global (not in the visual tree) and one that is defined on a specific page xaml. I haven't gotten around to dealing with the global yet, but I was hoping to get the page specific one working.

Here is my xaml:

```
    x:Class="Views.MainPanorama"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" 
    xmlns:toolkitPrimitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>

<ScrollViewer x:Name="mainScroll">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource BackgroundStyle}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image x:Name="icon" Source="/Folder;component/Images/Icons/logo.png" Height="24" Width="175" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20, 15, 0, 0" />
        <controls:Panorama Name="panMain" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource PanoramaHeaderTemplate}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0, -10, 0, 0" Height="680">
            <!--Panorama definition here-->
        </controls:Panorama>
        <gbl:SecureFooter ShowLock="True" x:Name="panoFoot" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="24, 24, 24, 0" />

        <Popup x:Name="_popup" Grid.Row="3" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The page works and the popup appears, but when I rotate the phone or emulator, the contents of the popup don't change orientation.

I'm setting the contents of the popup in code using:

```
_popup.Child = new OneOfTwoPopupUserControls();
```

Could this be causing the popup to ignore orientation? Does it need to have the full contents inside it when it's created in the xaml?

Comment: Do your own popup It seems that is the only way to handle it properly

Comment: What do you mean? I am doing my own popup? I'm creating the user controls and setting them as a child in the popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand Popup lives outside the visual tree of the Page, since the Page is what handles the Orientation changes the Popup itself is not affected.

The only solution I've worked with is listening to the orientation changed events and doing my own transform of the popup contents. Not ideal and didn't work well for me. In the end I discarded the Popup.

Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like you're right. We've tried all sorts of things and the only way it works is to manually rotate it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add the Popup to the visual tree, use the following line, the Popup rotates correctly:

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(popupInstance);
```

Comment: This worked for me. Just add the line before popup.IsOpen = true; I close my popup if orientation changes as well.

Answer (score 2):

Its actually quite simple to rotate the Popup - or its content to be precise - according to orientation. All you have to do is to listen to Orientation changes ...

```
static PhoneApplicationFrame ApplicationRootFrame
{
  get { return ((PhoneApplicationFrame) Application.Current.RootVisual); }
}

ApplicationRootFrame.OrientationChanged += OnOrientationChanged
```

And do something like the code below does. The TransformGroup ensures that the Popup content is rotated around the center of the content.

```
private static void ApplyOrientationTransform(PageOrientation orientation, FrameworkElement popupContent)
{
  TransformGroup group;

  switch (orientation)
  {
    case PageOrientation.LandscapeRight:
      group = new TransformGroup();
      group.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform { X = -popupContent.ActualWidth / 2, Y = -popupContent.ActualHeight / 2 });
      group.Children.Add(new RotateTransform {CenterX = 0, CenterY = 0, Angle = -90});
      group.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform { X = popupContent.ActualWidth / 2, Y = popupContent.ActualHeight / 2 });
      popupContent.RenderTransform = group;
      break;
    case PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
      group = new TransformGroup();
      group.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform { X = -popupContent.ActualWidth / 2, Y = -popupContent.ActualHeight / 2 });
      group.Children.Add(new RotateTransform {CenterX = 0, CenterY = 0, Angle = 90});
      group.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform { X = popupContent.ActualWidth / 2, Y = popupContent.ActualHeight / 2 });
      popupContent.RenderTransform = group;
      break;
    default:
      popupContent.RenderTransform = null;
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did originally try the answer as described by Oliver, but found the sizing of the popup needed changing for the information I was trying to display. I cheated a little to complete a similar issue I was having.

Initially I had all of the popup rendering calculated in the showPopup method:

```
private void showPopup()
    {
        Session session = App.getSession();
        Template template = session.getTemplate();

        border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
        border.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
        int initialMargin ;
        int landMargin ; // margin for information if displayed in landscape orientation
        StackPanel stkPnlOuter = new StackPanel();
        stkPnlOuter.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        stkPnlOuter.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;
        stkPnlOuter.Tap += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs>(stkPnlOuter_Tap);
        if (this.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp || this.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitDown)
        {
            initialMargin = 0;
            landMargin = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            initialMargin = 5;
            landMargin = 10;
        }

        TextBlock txt_blk1 = new TextBlock();
        txt_blk1.Text = "Loaded Type:";
        txt_blk1.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        txt_blk1.FontSize = 20;
        txt_blk1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        txt_blk1.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
        txt_blk1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        TextBlock txt_blk2 = new TextBlock();
        txt_blk2.Text = template.templateType == TemplateType.TYPE.TEMPLATE_FILE ? "Valido Template File" : "Valido Assessment File";
        txt_blk2.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        txt_blk2.FontSize = 20;
        txt_blk2.Margin = new Thickness(5,initialMargin, 5, initialMargin);
        txt_blk2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        TextBlock txt_blk3 = new TextBlock();
        txt_blk3.Text = "Template Type:";
        txt_blk3.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        txt_blk3.FontSize = 20;
        txt_blk3.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        txt_blk3.Margin = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 5);
        txt_blk3.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        TextBlock txt_blk4 = new TextBlock();
        txt_blk4.Text = TemplateClassification.getName();
        txt_blk4.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        txt_blk4.FontSize = 20;
        txt_blk4.Margin = new Thickness(5, landMargin, 5, initialMargin);
        txt_blk4.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        TextBlock txt_blk5 = new TextBlock();
        txt_blk5.Text = "Client Reference:";
        txt_blk5.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        txt_blk5.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        txt_blk5.FontSize = 20;
        txt_blk5.Margin = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 5);
        txt_blk5.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        TextBlock txt_blk6 = new TextBlock();
        txt_blk6.Text = template.ClientRef == null ? "-" : template.ClientRef;
        txt_blk6.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        txt_blk6.FontSize = 20;
        txt_blk6.Margin = new Thickness(5, landMargin, 5, initialMargin);
        txt_blk6.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        TextBlock txt_blk7 = new TextBlock();
        txt_blk7.Text = "Template Code:";
        txt_blk7.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        txt_blk7.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        txt_blk7.FontSize = 20;
        txt_blk7.Margin = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 5);
        txt_blk7.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        TextBlock txt_blk8 = new TextBlock();
        txt_blk8.Text = template.Code;
        txt_blk8.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        txt_blk8.FontSize = 20;
        txt_blk8.Margin = new Thickness(5, landMargin, 5, initialMargin);
        txt_blk8.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        TextBlock txt_blk9 = new TextBlock();
        txt_blk9.Text = "Template Title:";
        txt_blk9.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        txt_blk9.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        txt_blk9.FontSize = 20;
        txt_blk9.Margin = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 5);
        txt_blk9.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        TextBlock txt_blk10 = new TextBlock();
        txt_blk10.Text = template.Title;
        txt_blk10.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        txt_blk10.FontSize = 20;
        txt_blk10.Margin = new Thickness(5, landMargin, 5, initialMargin);
        txt_blk10.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        TextBlock txt_blk11 = new TextBlock();
        txt_blk11.Text = "Modified Date:";
        txt_blk11.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        txt_blk11.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        txt_blk11.FontSize = 20;
        txt_blk11.Margin = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 5);
        txt_blk11.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        TextBlock txt_blk12 = new TextBlock();
        txt_blk12.Text = Valido_CA.modCommon.DateFromString(template.ModifiedDate);
        txt_blk12.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        txt_blk12.FontSize = 20;
        txt_blk12.Margin = new Thickness(5, landMargin, 5, 5);
        txt_blk12.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        if (this.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp || this.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitDown)
        {


            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(txt_blk1);
            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(txt_blk2);
            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(txt_blk3);
            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(txt_blk4);
            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(txt_blk5);
            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(txt_blk6);
            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(txt_blk7);
            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(txt_blk8);
            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(txt_blk9);
            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(txt_blk10);
            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(txt_blk11);
            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(txt_blk12);
        }
        else
        {
            StackPanel stkPnlLeft = new StackPanel();
            stkPnlLeft.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;
            stkPnlLeft.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            StackPanel stkPnlRight = new StackPanel();
            stkPnlRight.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;
            stkPnlRight.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

            stkPnlOuter.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;

            stkPnlLeft.Children.Add(txt_blk1);
            stkPnlRight.Children.Add(txt_blk2);
            stkPnlLeft.Children.Add(txt_blk3);
            stkPnlRight.Children.Add(txt_blk4);
            stkPnlLeft.Children.Add(txt_blk5);
            stkPnlRight.Children.Add(txt_blk6);
            stkPnlLeft.Children.Add(txt_blk7);
            stkPnlRight.Children.Add(txt_blk8);
            stkPnlLeft.Children.Add(txt_blk9);
            stkPnlRight.Children.Add(txt_blk10);
            stkPnlLeft.Children.Add(txt_blk11);
            stkPnlRight.Children.Add(txt_blk12);

            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(stkPnlLeft);
            stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(stkPnlRight);
        }

        StackPanel stkPnlInner = new StackPanel();
        stkPnlInner.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
        stkPnlInner.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        Button btn_OK = new Button();
        btn_OK.Content = "OK";
        btn_OK.Width = 100;
        btn_OK.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_OK_Click);



        stkPnlInner.Children.Add(btn_OK);
        stkPnlInner.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        stkPnlOuter.Children.Add(stkPnlInner);

        border.Child = stkPnlOuter;
        if (this.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp || this.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitDown)
        {
            border.Width = 350;
            border.Height = 500;
            transforBorder(border);
            infoPopup.Child = border;

            infoPopup.IsOpen = true;
            infoPopup.VerticalOffset = (this.ActualHeight - border.Height) / 2;
            infoPopup.HorizontalOffset = (this.ActualWidth - border.Width) / 2;
        }
        else
        {

            border.Width = 600;
            border.Height = 350;
            transforBorder(border);
            infoPopup.Child = border;
            infoPopup.IsOpen = true;
            infoPopup.HorizontalOffset = (this.ActualHeight - border.Width) / 2;
            infoPopup.VerticalOffset = (this.ActualWidth - border.Height) / 2;
        }



    }
```

then in the OrientationChanged method I used the infoPopup.IsOpen = false, then called the showPopup method again.

Possibly a slightly sloppy way of doing this, but because I needed to change the width and height of the border I found this a simple was to complete the task.